# Is a chart/plot considered a figure? Are there “best practices” for charts/plots?

Tags: pgfplots, floats, best-practices, charts

I'm seriously confused as to what a “chart” or plot is considered in the LaTeX community.

Alright, let's start here. I've noticed individuals mainly use two methods for inserting charts:

1. Construct a chart from an external (to LaTeX) tool -> convert to PDF/PNG -> insert via `\usepackage{pdfpages}`.
2. Construct directly in LaTeX using `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

I see no problem with either; however, both methods entail different functions for inserting and different options for labeling. Because of this, I've noticed examples that enclose the entire plot in a figure so as to be able to include `\label{}` and `\caption{}`, which makes referencing easy. Others examples seem to imply that labeling the plot(s) (via `\legend{}` parameter) might be enough. And others simply use `\title{}`, but it would look weird if you enclose it in a `\figure{}` using `\caption{}`.

Another confusing bit for me, with the assumption that a chart is a figure, is proper placement for the title. Charts are easily identified when the title is on top, but best practices for figures entail the label be on the bottom.

And if the assumption (chart == figure) is wrong, then should there be a separate "List of" for Charts, aside from Tables and Figures? (Background: I'm writing my thesis so that's why I've got the "List of blahblah" pages.)

Anyway, by the tone of my question, you can already tell how unsure I am, so I'm not sure if I'm just overthinking this or what. I also understand that the nature of this question is sort of subjective, so if this question has to be closed, then I accept that fully.

Comment: Well, this is a matter of taste rather. In final it is a figure. If you want to complicate the whole affair you have to provide the code for `list of charts` yourself.

Comment: Don’t put a »List of Tables/Figures/Theorems/...«.  It is absolutely useless.  I didn’t put any in my thesis even though the guidelines require it and nobody noticed.

Comment: Also, asking questions à la »What do you think is better?« are primarily opinion-based and closed for that reason.

Comment: Henri, I quite agree that these lists are pretty useless. However, recommending to omit them if thesis regulations explicitly demand them is not right; it will leave a poor impression when it is noticed and just means asking for trouble.

Comment: I treat plots as figures; in fact, I often have figures that combine a plot with some other graphic such as a chemical drawing or conceptual cartoon. If you find it important, you can use the `float` package to define custom floats that will be separately numbered and listed; but it seems like a needless complication. KISS is usually the correct approach.

Comment: If your chart is converted to png/pdf, it is simpler to insert it via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Bernard Not just simpler, but required if you want to give it a caption, for example.

Comment: What is a `chart` exactly? That is, it seems to me that there are many kinds of charts and you might be talking about any of them. I don't know this matters, but I'm not really sure exactly what the issue here is. If your charts are like tables, for example, you could use `table` rather than `figure`.

Comment: @cfr: There's `\captionof` if one wants to complexify things…

Comment: @Bernard I was more thinking of getting it onto the same page. I suppose you could use `pagecommand`.